# Excel - total count of records where all 3 columns of data are blank

Tags: excel, countif, isnull

I'm trying to create a formula that provides the total count of records in column A that either have a null or 0 across all 3 columns.
Ex

```
Name    Score1 Score2 Score3
Test A
Test B           90
Test C
Test D.   0             0
```

In this example the total would be 3 because there are 3 Test that don't have a score entered.

**Most importantly it will need to be dynamic as the Row #'s can grow. Can I incorporate the count of non blanks in column A to let the formula know how far down to check?

I'm sure it's simple but none of my approaches are working. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you open to creating an additional column that does a summation of the scores? If so, it becomes pretty straightforward.

Comment: Is `0` considered a score or not?

Comment: @Marc Hey, no, I prefer nested as it is apart of a much larger report.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Hey, no, 0 and nulls don't countas scores.

Comment: Try `=COUNTA(A2:A5)-SUMPRODUCT(--(OR(B2:B5>0,C2:C5>0, D2:D5>0)))`

Comment: That worked. Would it still work if I used the entire column as the row count will change and just subtract 1 for the header?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad actually OR(B2:B7>0,C2:C7>0,D2:D7>0) will give TRUE if any cell in table is >0, so full formula will give result counta -1 or just counta if all table is empty

Comment: Quite right, but I see you provided a good solution below

Answer (score 1):

If all values are either blank or numeric (and >=0) only that would work:

```
=SUM(BYROW(B2:D7,LAMBDA(a,IF(SUM(a)=0,1,0))))
```

[image]

Adapt range `B2:D7` according to yours.

UPDATE:

```
=SUM(BYROW(B2:D7,LAMBDA(a,IF(SUM(COUNTIF(a,{"0",""}))=COLUMNS(a),1,0))))
```

Will work with both text and negative values. It will count if all values in row are blank or 0 or any combination of it:

[image]

Comment: This also assumes that values are >=0, which is likely a safe assumption.

Comment: Good point, @BigBen . It might be I made hasty assumption on too small example data.

Comment: What about this: `=SUM(N(BYROW(B2:D5, LAMBDA(a, SUM(N(a<>0))))=0))`? This is even shorter than my shortest version.

Comment: Way much better!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
=SUM(N(MMULT(N(B2:D5<>0), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B2:D5),,1,0))=0))
```

[image: output]

The condition: `N(B2:D5<>0)` serves to check cells that have a value different than zero and also non-blank cells.

Here using a shorter way to generate an array column of ones:

```
=SUM(N(MMULT(N(B2:D5<>0), TOCOL(N(B1:D1<>"")))=0))
```